# Pass all arguments through to inner function

Tags: javascript

If you are, as an example, creating a recursive function, where you're mutating your arguments as you pass them along, is there a way to simplify the nested call so you're not duplicating the entire function header inside of the function body?

Take this very constructed example:

```
const countdown = (min, someOtherStuff1, someOtherStuff2, someOtherStuff3, curr) => {
    if(curr == min){
        return 
    }
    console.log(--curr)
    countdown(min, someOtherStuff1, someOtherStuff2, someOtherStuff3, curr)
}
```

Is there a way where I can maintain this style of header with named parameters:

```
const countdown = (min, someOtherStuff1, someOtherStuff2, someOtherStuff3, curr) => { ... }
```

But re-call the function with all provided arguments inside the function something like

```
console.log(--curr)
countdown(...args)
```

[function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) seem to require me to not have named parameters from how I understand it.

Comment: "*function.apply seem to require me to not have named parameters*" no, it just requires you to pass an array-like. `fn = (a, b, c) => { fn.apply(null, [a, b, c]); }` is a valid call and it uses named parameters. Just isn't terribly convenient.

Comment: @VLAZ Hehe yeah that's not particularly shorter! :D

Comment: Make countdown having only one parameter which is an object, with min, someOtherstufs... as parameters of the object.
Your function will be:
function `countdown(obj) { if(obj.curr == obj.min) {return} obj.cur -= 1; countdown(obj);}`

Comment: @HediZitouni Yeah that's an option but it obfuscates the real function header just as much as countdown(arg) -> countdown(...arg) does

Comment: Ok, another solution is to use "arguments" which is available on each declared functions (be carefull, it is not available on arrow functions) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: @HediZitouni A shame that it doesn't work for arrow functions, but aside from that it's essentially what I want, good find! :D